# What controls the Google Maps traffic widget updating "time to arrive"?

Tags: google-maps

I have the Google Maps traffic widget on my Galaxy Nexus.  The widget will show the traffic lights, but the times don't seem to update unless I log into maps by tapping the widget such that Maps loads.  Is there a way to "force" the travel time for Google Maps widgets to always display, from the current location?